# Implementing a online compiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a small project which is to host a site similar to ideone.com ie to host an online compiler which will compile and run the code which is given as an input.I am using ROR for the backend part.

What I have done is that the code which is inputted in the textbox is stored into the string and I am using system calls in ruby to create a file and I am storing the string in that  file.Similary I am also storing the input for the code in another file.Again I am using system calls to compile and run the file and storing the output into the string and sending it to the front end part.

I have got two problems for the above implemented method
1) It will only work for a single user at a time.Any idea how to implement for multiple users and if yes what will be the limit of the number of users?
2) Anyone can put a malicious code and harm the system.I have to sandbox the environment such that it will run at an isolated environment. How can I do it?

Program running infinity loop is not a problem as I have put the limit on the execution time.I am using backtick to execute the shell script.I am implementing it for C, if I succeed to solve all the problems I would extend it to other languages.

Comment: What kind of code are people uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of not letting people wipe out your hard drive, install spambots etc, you will need to run all code inside a virtual machine, to protect the host.  This also solves the user problem since you can spin up a virtual machine for each user and spin it down after running the code.  However, this might use a lot of resources on your server.

I'd be interested to find out what ideone.com does.  I suspect that everything runs in the client's browser, which is obviously much safer since you can just use your server to save their code, but not actually run it.  If it runs in their browser it is sandboxed anyway.  Are you sure that you don't want to do this instead?  I've never heard of anyone letting people upload code and then run it on the system server.  Seems kind of insanely risky.

Comment: Automated checkers on programming competitions always compile and execute foreign code, it's rather common task. I think they use virtual machines for these purposes, as you suggested.